# meteor loginWithFacebook disable auto-creation of account

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

What i want to do is have separate buttons for "Login with Facebook" and "Sign-up with Facebook". Mainly i want to do this because i require to know if users accepted the "terms and conditions" (or smth similar) before creating an account.

What i managed to do is disable the new account creation using this

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function(user) {
    return false;
});
```

How can i get on the server side the status of the checkbox on client? Or how can i pass to `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` something that can be accessed on `validateNewUser` ?